# .htaccess redirecting all requests to /home/aaa/public_html to /home/bbb/public_html?

Tags: .htaccess

Is there any way to redirect all requests to **/home/aaa/public_html** which is the document root of aaa.com, requests such as:

```
https://www.aaa.com/
https://www.aaa.com/xyz/def.jpg
https://www.aaa.com/account/login.php
```

To the corresponding files in **/home/bbb/public_html**, as:

```
/home/bbb/public_html/index.php
/home/bbb/public_html/xyz/def.jpg
/home/bbb/public_html/account/login.php
```

Is there any way to achieve this by /home/aaa/public_html/.htaccess ?

So that all the actual website files are in **/home/bbb/public_html** but the requests are being sent to https://www.aaa.com/ whose document is actually **/home/aaa/public_html**

I'm not looking to redirect on the HTTP level but on the file system level. Is this possible? How?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to serve **all** requests from `/home/bbb/public_html` then why not make it `DocumentRoot` ?

Comment: Because of some legacy reasons. Can this be done at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `alias` directive you can achieve it. Place following snippet inside your `VirtualHost` section:

```
Alias / /home/bbb/public_html/

<Directory /home/bbb/public_html>
   Options Indexes
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

---

However keep in mind that doing it by setting a new `DocumentRoot` is fairly simple by just using a single line Apache server config:

```
DocumentRoot /home/bbb/public_html
```

Comment: I want both /home/aaa/public_html and /home/bbb/public_html to be working as independent domains but they are being backed up by the same code base. So I think a new DocumentRoot won't work since I need both of them working?

Comment: `https://www.aaa.com/` can either show content from either `/home/aaa/public_html/index.php` OR `/home/bbb/public_html/index.php` but how can it show content from both files. May be you can do this with another sub-domain or a new directory path i.e. `https://www.aaa.com/b/`